# How to create diagonal and unequal matrix in R?

Tags: r

I need to create a diagonal (6,6) matrix in r using this valuse 1.2, 12.1, 6.5, 9.4, 4.9, 2.4. How it should be the R code?

Comment: Maybe the function `diag`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `diag`:

```
diag(c(1.2, 12.1, 6.5, 9.4, 4.9, 2.4))
```